# passing an array of structs from a function to the main program

Tags: c

I have a data file of about 2500 lines. Each line contains 5 parameters.  I declare a strut out side of a routine.

```
typedef struct data
{

char date[9];
char time[3];
float price;
float NAV;
float percent_change;
} _data ;

void readfile(int *j, struct data *input);

void readfile(int *j,struct data *input)
```

I set aside memory  to read each line of the file into an array of structs.

```
input = calloc(days_of_data,sizeof(*input));
for (i = 0; i< days_of_data; i++)
    input[i] = *(_data*)calloc(1,sizeof(_data));
```

and read the file.

```
while(fgets(line, 75, fp) != NULL)
{      

    date = strtok(line,",");
    strcpy(input[i].date,date);
    time = strtok(NULL,",");
    strcpy(input[i].time, time);
    price = strtok(NULL,",");
    input[i].price = atof(price);
    NAV = strtok(NULL,",");
    input[i].NAV = atof(NAV);
    percent_change = strtok(NULL,",");
    input[i].percent_change =  atof(percent_change);
    i--;

}
```

This works.  Now I want to sent the structure to the main program.

```
int main(int argc, const char * argv[]) {
struct data *input;
readfile(&j, input);
printf("%f\n",input[0].percent_change);
}
```

This compiles but crashes on the print statement.

Answer (score 1):

You will have to use return value

```
struct data * readfile(int *j) {
    struct data *input;
    /* read the data */
    return input;
}

int main(int argc, const char * argv[]) {
    struct data *input;
    input = readfile(&j);
    printf("%f\n",input[0].percent_change);
}
```

or pointer

```
void readfile(int *j, struct data **input_out) {
    struct data *input;
    /* read the data */
    *input_out = input;
}

int main(int argc, const char * argv[]) {
    struct data *input;
    readfile(&j, &input);
    printf("%f\n",input[0].percent_change);
}
```

to pass the data to the caller.

Comment: that is right, or even `j=readFile(&input);` for   `int readFile(struct data **input_out)`

Comment: @milevyo I'm not sure if it is right because I don't know how `j` (the argument) is used in `readfile` and how `j` (a global variable?) is used in `main` or other parts of the program.

Comment: it is an unused variable, it let us just guess that it returns nb items or the sizeof the struct input

Comment: I tried both methods. Both ran but printed out 0.000000 which is the wrong value.  j is not pertinent to the issue at hand.

Comment: This won't be the cause, but `input[i] = *(_data*)calloc(1,sizeof(_data));` do cause memory leak. Just don't do it.

Comment: Why do you do `i--;` after reading one line? Do you have proper (not too many nor too less) number of line in the file? Are you sure you won't access out of range (`input[days_of_data]` or further, `input[-1]` or less)?